# How to play video from NSData

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata, playback

I would like to know if it's possible to play a video from an NSData object... with the MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Where do you get the data from?

Comment: from my db... not from bundle...

Comment: Just a heads up for the future reader,  the MPMoviePlayerController has been deprecated ... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ben's answer works perfectly on simulator but wont work on the device, You cannot write anywhere on the device. Check code below

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMove.mp4"];

    [videoData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    NSURL *moveUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
    [player setContentURL:moveUrl];
    player.view.frame = viewPlayer.bounds;
    [viewPlayer addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];
```

Comment: ops! i cant believe i just answered a one year old question...:)

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without writing to a file?

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:videoPath contents:videoData attributes:nil];

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. If the data comes from your DB, can you save it into a temporary file and play that?

Comment: yes but I would like to avoid this... ;) I'm trying to do this with QTKit framework now...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use NSFileManager in this case instead writeToFile

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMove.mp4"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:videoData attributes:nil];

NSURL *moveUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
[player setContentURL:moveUrl];
player.view.frame = viewPlayer.bounds;
[viewPlayer addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

Comment: What are the advantages using createFileAtPath vs writeToFile?

Answer (score -4):

1. create a file with the type of your NSData for example if your NSData is type of mp4 create a file with that type - for example - "myMove.mp4"
2. copy past the file to your app resurces
3. add this code

   ```
   NSData *mediaData; //your data    
   NSString *movePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMove" ofType:@"mp4"];         
   [mediaData writeToFile:movePath atomically:YES];        
   NSURL *moveUrl= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movePath];    
   MPMoviePlayerController *movePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];          
   [movePlayer setContentURL:moveUrl]; 
   [movePlayer play];
   ```

Comment: this won't work on the device, you cant write files anywhere on the device. Check out my answer bellow..