# How to create video player which take nsdata as input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, nsdata, audio-player

I want to create a video player which takes NSData as input. Most of player like `AVPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayer` takes url or file location to play a video. I do not want to convert my `NSData` to file.  Requirement for this is that I do not want to save my file as someone can take it through jailbreak.

Comment: Welcome to SO pankaz, while your question is being answered please read [FAQ].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play video from NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026620/how-to-play-video-from-nsdata)

Comment: @trick14 All answer at your link is writing file at a path and then creating url  to pass in player but i do not want to write a file. MY main concern is to protect my video content .If I write file then people can get access to it through jailbreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this is not an answer.
I don't have enough reputations to comment.

As far as I know, to playback with iOS built-in players, you need to launch local HTTP server for that.
In fact, most of media DRM solutions does something like that.
Be careful to access control anyway. And you need jailbreak checking of course.

Comment: yes you  are right but there is no need to jailbreak your device. Use GCD web server with Kxmovie player.