# iOS, Downloader amr video with NSData. How to play?

Tags: ios, video, amr

iOS4+ is not support to play amr video,  I downloaded the amr video with NSData, 
used third party source to convert amr to wav, but it does not succeed.

Comment: you can't play video from nsdata. You have to write video file in document directory from nsdata and play that video file

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026620/how-to-play-video-from-nsdata

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the [VLC Media Library](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) which is open source and supports .amr. However it is licensed under the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html).